# LaTeX Таблица и связанный с ней текст

Tags: документация, latex, tex

Задача такая: Я составляю документацию на карту регистров устройства.(Регистры отражают состояние устройства и позволяют управлять им)
Необходимо в начале документа составить карту регистров(их название, адрес, краткое описание, возможно примечание), а затем расширенное текстовое описание каждого регистра. Хотелось бы, чтобы название регистров их адреса были только в доном месте, а между строками таблицы и описанием существовала однозначная связь. Как это сделать? Заранее признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: судя по описанию, это чем-то похоже на библиографию, по поводу работы с которой есть много информации (в т.ч. и на русском).